# How do I remount /home as the ec2-user in Ansible?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, mount

I can manually remount /home as the ec2-user by executing these three lines:

```
$ cd /
$ exec sudo -i
# mount -a
```

How do I do this in Ansible without rebooting?

Edit:
/home is on a separate volume.
No other users are on the box.
The `cd /` removes usage of /home.
The `exec sudo -i` kills the ec2-user process, which was using /home, and leaves me logged in as root.
Now I can unmount and mount home without problems.

Comment: Why do you need to do this in the first place? Is the volume not configured to be mounted automatically?

Comment: I need to move the data on the volume to a bigger volume. So I change the /etc/fstab and remount. And yes, it is configured to mount automatically in fstab.